When building a photon map, if I observe a diffuse reflection from a phong material, how is the throughput updated?
I am using russian roulette to determine whether a photon is diffuse reflected, specular reflected, or absorbed by the phong material.
If a diffuse reflection occurs, I sample the direction of the reflected photon with a uniform hemisphere.
Because of russian roulette, I divided the throughput by the probability that the diffuse reflection occurred. I also divide the throughput by the number of photons before tracing it through the scene. Do I further multiply it by the PDF of a uniform hemipshere?
And where does lambertian modelling come into play? Is the idea of sampling a diffuse reflection like this the lambertian model?
Also, does the logic make sense? I have a max depth to avoid infinite reflection and do it for all photons to build a photon map.
Many thanks!
